# Function written to insert data to an empty table but it is not inserting the data

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add data to an empty table using the function.
When tried to display the output by using the "Raise info" command, it is working fine.
When I am trying the same with the "insert"  statement, it is not working out.
No data is inserting into the table.
My code looks like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_upd_invoice5(personid integer)
      RETURNS integer
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
      COST 100.0
      VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $function$
DECLARE
Begin 
  /* none of the insert is working
  INSERT INTO public.invoice(
      pk_invoice_id, fk_person_id, invoice_no, invoice_date, gross_amount, 
  discount_amount, net_amount, invoice_desc, created_date_time, created_by,             
  modified_date_time, modified_by, active)
      select 999999776, 5,1, to_date('08/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'), 9500, 0, 
  7283, 'Rent for the month of november 
  2018',to_date('08/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') , 1, 
  to_date('08/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'), 1, 'Y';
  */    
  -- PREPARE invoiceprep1 (int) AS
      INSERT INTO tmp1 VALUES($1);
  -- EXECUTE invoiceprep1 (returnsiid);
  /*
  PREPARE invoiceprep1 (int, int, varchar, date, int, int, int, varchar, date, 
  int, date, int, char) AS
      INSERT INTO invoice VALUES($1, $2, $3, 
  $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13);
  EXECUTE invoiceprep1 
(returnsiid,returnspi,tmpinvoiceno,tmpstartdate,returnspr,returnsdis,returnspr,tempdesc,tmpstartdate,tmpuserId,tmpstartdate,tmpuserId,tmpActive);
  */
  /*
  INSERT INTO invoice(pk_invoice_id, fk_person_id, invoice_no, invoice_date, gross_amount, discount_amount, net_amount, invoice_desc, created_date_time, created_by, modified_date_time, modified_by, active) 
       VALUES(returnsiid,returnspi,returnsiid,tmpstartdate,returnspr,returnsdis,returnspr,tempdesc,tmpstartdate,1,tmpstartdate,1,'Y');
  -- commit;
  */
  --  update invoice set pk_invoice_id = 99999999;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
          RAISE;
  return 1;
End;  
$function$;
```

Comment: Hi Mungara Pallavi Welcome to stackoverflow. Which Database are you talking about MYSQL, SQL SERVER OR POSTGRESQL? Could you update your tags for us please?

Comment: Hello pnorton, Thanks for your reply. I am working on PostgreSQL version 9.6

Comment: Thank  Mungara Pallavi

Comment: What exactly does "not work" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, which one exactly (please **[edit]** your question and add it). Did you `commit` your insert?

Comment: when I am calling the function, it is throwing error as "Control reached the end of the  Function without return ".It is displaying the tmpdispvalues result,but it is not inserting into the table.

Comment: You need to show us the **complete** `create function` statement, rather than just a part of it.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_upd_invoice4(personid integer)

Comment: I have posted the full function. Some of the inserts are commented as I was trying. None of these are working.

Answer (score 0):

Any error will cause the whole transaction including your `INSERT`s to be rolled back. That is why you don't see the effects.

The error message indicates that there is no `RETURN` statement at the end of the function, but the function is declared to return something else than `void`.

Comment: Your statement "return 1;" MUST come before the Exception section. As it stands the return statement could only run if an exception occurred, but the raise immediately terminates your scrip and rolls back your inserts. So move the statement, perhaps even better just remove "Exception ... raise;"